# GWT ImageLoadingCell - Setting specific size

Tags: image, gwt

I'm loading images into a table using an ImageLoadingCell, which simply takes the URL of the image. Is there a way to set the size of the image, so the browser will make the images a consistent size?

Answer (score 0):

[Developer's Guide - Creating Custom Cells](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html)

you can change default template `@Template("<img src=\"{0}\"/>")` for renderer, for example to  `@Template("<img src=\"{0}\" height=\"100px\" width=\"100px\"/>")`,
see file ImageLoadingCell.class line number 70